How to create kubernetes generic secret without base64 encoding?
for example I'm creating a kubernetes generic secret using following:
kubectl create secret generic passwords \
--from-literal=TestUser='mypass' -n mynamespace

And I will get the following secret:
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
data:
  TestUser: bXlwYXNz
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-07-19T16:32:07Z"
  name: passwords
  namespace: mynamespace
  resourceVersion: "8419787023"
  uid: fc203ef1-5aca-4e54-afe8-171a6062be48
type: Opaque

But as you can see the password is encoded in base64, how can I disable the encoding just to have a plain text?
TestUser: mypass
I could not find this information in kubernetes documentation.
Thanks.

echo "bXlwYXNz" | base64 --decode -> mypass%


But as you can see the password is encoded in base64, how can I disable the encoding just to have a plain text?

You can't. Secret values are always represented as base64 encoded text when you view the manifest (because it's not uncommon for secrets to contain binary data). If you expose the secrets inside a pod as environment variables or as files, you will see the un-encoded value.
If you just want to view an existing secret, you can do something like this:
kubectl get -n mynamespace secret passwords -o json |
  jq '.data|map_values(@base64d)'

Which will produce as output:
{
  "TestUser": "mypass"
}

